# How do I import my Sketchup Free project into Blender?

Tags: modeling

I've tried to import using STL but it wont zoom properly as shown in this video.

Oh, this forum doesn't allow videos. How are we supposed to communicate?

Here are some screen shots:
[image]

I spent ages creating screen shots but this site won't let me add them.

Comment: See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)